# How can I read generic xml into a generic hierarchical class

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, hierarchy

Basically I want to write a generic XML viewer...  Given something like:

```
<Settings>
    <User Name="Terry" BDay="09-01-1966">
        <Spouse>
            <Name>Jerri</Name>
        </Spouse>
    </User>
    <User Name="Cliff" BDay="10-18-1980"/>
</Settings>
```

and display it something like:

```
Settings =    
    User =        
        .Name = Terry
        .BDay = 09-01-1966
        Spouse =
            Name = Jerri        
    User =
        .Name = Cliff
        .BDay = 10-18-1980
```

Attributes are noted by a period before the tag name and child nodes and attributes are indented.

I thought to use a class something like:

```
public class XHierarchy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<XHierarchy> Items { get; set; } = new List<XHierarchy>();
}
```

If I manually create some test data, my model / class works fine.  The issue I am having is figuring out how to read the data from an xml file into the class.  I want this to work for ANY valid xml, not just something that follows the schema of the test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XHierarchy xHierarchy = new XHierarchy();
            xHierarchy.Parse(root);
        }
        public class XHierarchy
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Attributes { get; set; }
            public List<XHierarchy> Items { get; set; }

            public void Parse(XElement element)
            {
                Name = element.Name.LocalName;
                if (element.FirstNode != null)
                {
                    XmlNodeType type = element.FirstNode.NodeType;
                    if(type == XmlNodeType.Text) Value = element.FirstNode.ToString();
                }
                foreach(XAttribute attribute in element.Attributes())
                {
                    if (Attributes == null) Attributes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                    Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(attribute.Name.LocalName, (string)attribute));
                }
                foreach(XElement child in element.Elements())
                {
                    if (Items == null) Items = new List<XHierarchy>();
                    XHierarchy childHierarchy = new XHierarchy();
                    Items.Add(childHierarchy);
                    childHierarchy.Parse(child);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this works as is, but I removed the recursion by using a Stack<XElement>

Comment: A stack is not going to give proper parent/child relationships.